# Check if a drag value is increasing or decreasing in Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag, draggesture

How can I check if the drag value is increasing or decrease when dragging up or down. I want to know the direction someone is dragging in. Can anyone help with this??

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to start. Sorry. Haven't been writing code for too long. @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

I found a method for getting the direction of the scroll: https://medium.com/@Mos6yCanSwift/swift-ios-determine-scroll-direction-d48a2327a004

```
let currentVelocityY = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView.superview).y
let currentVelocityYSign = Int(currentVelocityY).signum()
        
if currentVelocityYSign != lastVelocityYSign && currentVelocityYSign != 0 {
            lastVelocityYSign = currentVelocityYSign
}
        
if lastVelocityYSign < 0 {
            
//CODE HERE
            
} else if lastVelocityYSign > 0 {
            
//CODE HERE

 }
```